# How to include only the result of an nodejs function into webpack bundle?

Tags: node.js, webpack

I have a nodejs app which exports a function, using that function I want to retreive the resulted object and include it in the webpack bundle. I tried webpack `magic comment webpackIgnore` but it also ignores to include the function result in the bundle. Like following:

```
const getConfig = import('../interface' /* webpackIgnore: true */);
const config = getConfig();
```

What I need is the `const config` result included in the bundle. How can I do that?

**Disclaimer:** this example is just a quick random snippet made to show the point.

Comment: You could write the config to a file and then `require("../theconfigfile.json")` so it will be included in your bundle. I don't think it's possible to evaluate the result of a method and include it in the webpack bundle.

Comment: @Rick I know how to include regular files, but here I need the result of a method. You're possibly right about not being possible but... I didn't lost my hope. Thank you.

Comment: You might want to look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55527419/how-can-i-evaluate-a-node-script-during-a-webpack-build-and-make-it-contents-ava

Answer (score -1):

you syntax is wrong, using:

```
// commonjs
const getConfig = require("../interface");
```

or

```
// module
import getConfig from "../interface"
```

if interface file using export default

Comment: Obviusly something is wrong, but this is not a solution to the question. The `getCOnfig` is proccessed without errors...